# Structure of $errors with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4 whenever on every request there is a variable `$errors` to show the errors that have happened in the request. IT has a structure like this:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#120 (2) {
  ["messages":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["email"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(40) "The email must be a valid email address."
    }
  }
  ["format":protected]=>
  string(8) ":message"
}
```

I figured I could put this code on the header of my app to give output to the user, listing all relevant message, like this:

```
@if (count($errors->messages))
    <div class="error-box">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->messages as $error)
                <li>{{{ $error }}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

But apparently I cant access the messages like this.

Can someone please explain me the structure of `MessageBar $errors`, and more importantly, how to loop through all the error messages, to display them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do `$errors->messages` directly because `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` has its messages property as `["messages":protected]`.

What you need to do is use `all()` like this:

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
     <li>{{{ $error }}}</li>
@endforeach
```

or in fact, since MessageBag can also behave as an array, you can do `count()` and `foreach` on it directly like:

```
@if (count($errors)) // or $errors->count()
    <div class="error-box">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors as $error)
                <li>{{{ $error }}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

You can also see the full list of methods you can perform with Laravel's MessageBag at:

- Laravel 4.1: http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html
- Laravel 4.2: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Unnawut's answer - you can also access errors like this

```
$errors->first();
```

So you can just get the first error without having to loop through them all. If you want a specific error relating to a specific group (like email) - you can do

```
$errors->first('email');
```